# Template Formatting in v-for in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**This code give me all player value & then all monster value. But I want the output format will be like: one player value then one monster value   ,,  one player value then one monster value**

```js
new Vue({
  el: app,
  data: {
    output: {
      player: [1, 5, 61, 98, 15, 315, 154, 65],
      monster: [2,14, 15, 113, 19, 22,12,54,64],
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>
    <h6 v-for="pla in output.player">Player value :{{pla}}</h6>
    <h6 v-for="mon in output.monster">Monster value :{{mon}}</h6>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through index, and wrap the player and monster in a template:

```js
new Vue({
  el: app,
  data: {
    output: {
      player: [1, 5, 61, 98, 15, 315, 154, 65],
      monster: [2,14, 15, 113, 19, 22,12,54,64],
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>
    <template v-for="i in output.player.length" :key="i">
      <h6>Player value :{{output.player[i]}}</h6>
      <h6>Monster value :{{output.monster[i]}}</h6>
    </template>
  </span>
</div>
```

Note: This assumes `player` and `monster` always have the same length, you need to handle the edge cases if they are not the same size.